# pre allocation of memory in Ruby and Python for hashes, akin to Perl's keys %hash = num

Tags: python, ruby, perl, hashtable, allocation

I may have to deal with very large hashes in future code. In Perl, if one knows in advance that a huge hash is to be created, then one can pre-allocate memory by using this code (assuming that one needs a 1 billion size hash):

```
keys %hash = 1e9
```

Is there something similar in Ruby or Python?

Comment: What do you try to achieve by doing that?

Comment: I want to achieve Higher Performance.

Comment: Higher than what? Is your program running too slowly? Have you demonstrated that the time spent allocating space for the data is excessive?

Comment: Ruby: https://github.com/rdp/google_hash

Comment: Yes, I have. The creation of the Hash is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Python `dict.fromkeys()` may be used to create a new dictionary with keys from seq and values set to value(In this case null).

```
dict.fromkeys(xrange(1000000))
```